Convert this socket server sketch from python to micro-python
#Imports modules
import socket
import time

listensocket = socket.socket() #Creates an instance of socket
Port = 8000 #Port to host server on
maxConnections = 999
IP = socket.gethostname() #IP address of local machine

listensocket.bind(('',Port))

#Starts server
listensocket.listen(maxConnections)
print("Server started at " + IP + " on port " + str(Port))

#Accepts the incomming connection
(clientsocket, address) = listensocket.accept()
print("New connection made!")

running = True

while running:
    message = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode() #Gets the incomming message
    print(message)

This sketch receives text from another computer and works great in python. When I run it in micro-python I get
attribute error, object has no attribute 'gethostname'
I am trying to send text from my pc to ESP32(Cardcomputer). The python sketch I use to send the text works in
both python and Micro-python without any modifications or problems.

Why do you need the IP here at all? It seems like it is only used for logging and to see the log output, you already need an active connection to the device and thus most likely know the corresponding IP yourself.

The solution was simple: I changed IP = socket.gethostname() to the actual IP address: IP = "192.166.192".
